# traverse JSON when object value is an array of objects with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my external JSON:

```
{"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 3}, "objects": [{"body": "this is copy text", "id": "1", "pub_date": "2011-05-04T12:23:26", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/entry/1/", "slug": "test-title-number-one", "title": "test title number one", "user": "/api/v1/user/1/"}, {"body": "this is the second test text", "id": "2", "pub_date": "2011-05-04T15:01:16", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/entry/2/", "slug": "second-test", "title": "Second test", "user": "/api/v1/user/1/"}, {"body": "item three", "id": "3", "pub_date": "2011-05-05T12:04:04", "resource_uri": "/api/v1/entry/3/", "slug": "item-3", "title": "item 3", "user": "/api/v1/user/1/"}]}
```

Here is my JS:

```
$.ajax({url: "/api/v1/entry/?format=json", 
dataType: "json",
success: function(json) {
    $.each(json.objects[0], function(key, value) { 
      alert(key + ': ' + value); 
    });
}
});
```

I can index the objects in the array with $.each(json.objects[0]..., but I need to be able to hit each object in the array and I don't know why simply $.each(json.objects... doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do a normal JS loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.objects.length; ++i)
{
   $.each(json.objects[i], function(key, value) { 
      alert(key + ': ' + value); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a full jQuery solution you can do:

```
$.each(json.objects, function(key, value) {
    $.each(json.objects[key], function(key, value){
        alert(key + ': ' + value);
    })
});
```

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LGC9X/ beware, lots of alerts :P