# Smile timeline widget Json feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, timeline

I have a [Smile timeline](http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/) widget on a site I'm building. I've followed couple of tutorials on how to implement and customize it, all good so far. However I can't find a way of using Json service instead of using the data stored in a global variable in a js file. I'm not great at javascript so I couldn't find a way to store the entire Json output (which is correcly formatted accordingly) in a global variable.

here's how the data in global variable should look:

```
var timeline_data = { 
'events' : [
        {'start': '2000',
        'title': 'Barfusserkirche',
        'description': 'by Lyonel Feininger, American/German Painter, 1871-1956',
        'image': 'http://images.allposters.com/images/AWI/NR096_b.jpg',
        'link': 'http://www.allposters.com/-sp/Barfusserkirche-1924-Posters_i1116895_.htm'
        },

        {'start': '2001',
        'end': '2004',
        'title': 'Three Figures',
        'description': 'by Kasimir Malevich, Ukrainian Painter, 1878-1935',
        'image': 'http://images.allposters.com/images/BRGPOD/75857_b.jpg',
        'link': 'http://www.allposters.com/-sp/Three-Figures-1913-28-Posters_i1349989_.htm'
        },

        {'start': '2002',            
        'end' : '2003',
        'title': 'Landschaft bei Montreuil',
        'description': 'by Albert Gleizes, French Painter, 1881-1953',
        'image': 'http://images.allposters.com/images/mer/1336_b.jpg',
        'link': 'http://www.allposters.com/-sp/Landschaft-bei-Montreuil-Posters_i339007_.htm',
        'isDuration' : true,
        'icon' : "red-ico.gif",        
        'color' : '#ffcc00',
        'textColor' : 'green'}
]}
```

and that's how it's called by the timeline:

```
var url = '.'; // The base url for image, icon and background image references in the data
eventSource1.loadJSON(timeline_data, url); // The data was stored into the timeline_data variable.
```

That's what I've tried but I'm stuck on how to store in the variable the entire output and not just one entry:

```
var timeline_data;//at global scope
$.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: '/timeline/json_output.json', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        timeout: 10000, 
        crossDomain: true, 
        success: function(result) {
            timeline_data = result;
        }
});
```

Now I don't know how to use timeline_data. Think it's an array object, don't know how to proceed further.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902560/traverse-json-when-object-value-is-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually find this [here](http://pratyush-chandra.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/store-ajax-json-response-into.html), and worked like a charm!

```
function getJson(url) {
 return JSON.parse($.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: url,
     dataType: 'json',
     global: false,
     async:false,
     success: function(data) {
         return data;
     }
 }).responseText);
}

var myJsonObj = getJson('myjsonurl');
```

Is there maybe a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var timeline_data;//at global scope
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: '/timeline/json_output.json', 
    dataType: 'json', 
    timeout: 10000, 
    crossDomain: true, 
    success: function(result) {
        for(var i = 0; i < result.events.length; ++i){
            $.each(result.events[i], function(key, value) { 
                console.log(key + ': ' + value); 
            });
        }
    }
});
```